# Issues connecting ASP.net membership to external MySQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, asp.net-membership

I'm working on a school project and I'm almost done. I created a C# website with different functions for different users.

I tested my website several times on my local machine and it works fine, even logging in with Google+ api etc works as it should.

But recently I uploaded my website to an ASP.net host (it's a free host, not Azure) and tested my project. Unfortunately signing in or registering both didn't work.
I did some research and found out you have to link your C# project to an online database (I know it's stupid but I honestly didn't know). 
So I ordered a free external SQL server and database to connect my project with and save all the required information by **ASP.net membership**.
But there is where I get the issues: I have to:

- **Copy all the required columns from my local database to my external database** e.g. username: VARCHAR(20) etc.
- **Connect to the external SQL database** by changing the connection string in the web.config file

Some detailed information:

**COPY ALL THE REQUIRED COLUMNS**

I searched how to do this and figured out Microsoft SQL Server Management Software is the best software to edit and view my database, tables and columns on my **local machine**, for my **external database** I'm using PHPMyAdmin.
The problem is I don't know how to log in to my local machine database to view all my tables and columns. Some people say the server name is just the name of your machine: [image: Signing in my local machine with machine name]

But that does not work.

Also, filling in just a period ('.') does not work:[image: logging in doesn't work]

And even when I got it working? What do I have to do to see the columns and their data from my local visual studio C# website?

**CHANGING THE CONNECTIONSTRING**
I don't understand the connection string and how to connect it to my SQL database hosted on freesqldatabases.com. How does it work? (I read all the Microsoft docs but could not figure out)

If anyone knows how to get this working it would be really nice and helpful!